# Mintegral Data Migration from REST API in Python

Tags: python, php, rest

Mintegral REST API document https://www.mintegral.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/1-Mintegral_Reporting-API.pdf

When I run this code in Python, it always returns `{"code":400,"msg":"Validation fails (Token Error)","data":null}` (screenshot attached)[image]

The API key and username are correct. I don't know why????

```
import requests
import time
import hashlib 

apikey = "xxxx"
encoded_timestamp = hashlib.md5(str(time.time()).encode())
token = apikey + encoded_timestamp.hexdigest()
md5_token = hashlib.md5(token.encode()).hexdigest()

response = requests.get("http://data.mintegral.com/v4.php?m=advertiser",
                        params = {
                        'username':'XXXABC'
                        ,'token':md5_token
                        ,'timestamp':str(int(time.time()))
                        # ,'utc':'+8'
                ,'start_date':'2022-06-07'
                ,'end_date':'2022-06-13'
                ,'Content-type': 'application/json'
                # ,'per_page':5000
                }
                )
response.text
```

But when I checked the example in PHP, it works.
Could you please help me to fix the Python code?
[image]
Anyone has experience about it?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Erik, I mean. The API key and username I use for The Python code are correct. Why does it return 400 error? Should I edit something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in logic. You use the `time.time()` function twice, once when creating token and second time while POST. Because of this, your hash is different from server hash.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was checking the implementation of Mintegral API in Python, and this was one of the first results in Google search, I would like to update the solution that worked for me.

I did not include the request, but in my example, it is clear how to generate tokens and shape the header.

You used a username instead of access-key in a header which might be for an older API call. The documentation for Mintegral API can be found [here](https://adv-new.mintegral.com/doc/en/introduction/token).

Both of the answers from 1rone were implemented in my solution. I saved the timestamp in a variable `now` and converted it to an integer as demanded in  Mintegral API documentation. (`time.time()` returns float)

```
import time
import hashlib

api_key = "api_key"
access_key = "access_key"

now = int(time.time())
token = hashlib.md5((api_key + hashlib.md5(str(now).encode()).hexdigest()).encode()).hexdigest()

header = {
    "access-key": access_key,
    "token": token,
    "timestamp": now
}
```